# In linq-to-entities, how to return objects with a filtered list of children?

Tags: c#-3.0, linq-to-entities

I have the following model

[image: EDMX model representing a ProductionBlock with 0 or many ProductionLog]

The first step is to select all the `ProductionBlock` with

```
var blocks = context.ProductionBlocks;
```

How can I combine the `ProductionLog` that has no end time with the `ProductionBlock`?

I tried to do it using a reverse lookup like

```
var blocks = context
    .ProductionLogs
    .Include("FK_ProductionLog_ProductionBlock")
    .Where(log => log.EndTime == null).Select(log => log.ProductionBlock)
    .Union(context.ProductionBlocks);
```

But the blocks don't contains any `ProductionLogs`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me know if i am off base, but you would want.

```
 var logs = (
       from pl in context.ProductionLogs.Include("ProductionBlock")
            where pl.EndTime == null
       select pl);
```

You would then have a list of logs and blocks.

```
var blocks  = logs.SelectMany(x=>x.ProductionBlock)
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to build from your suggestion and work out a solution `var blocks = context.ProductionLogs.Include("ProductionBlock").Where(log => log.EndTime == null).ToList().Select(log => log.ProductionBlock).Union(context.ProductionBlocks);` The ToList() there is because I have an Xml column and the Union is not working with an Xml column.